# Using the at and batch utilities with zsh on MacOs

Tags: macos, zsh

I am trying to schedule a one time job with the `at` utility. I am trying:
`at 13:00`, then hitting enter, then
`<name_of_shell_script>`,
then `ctrl+d`.

The top line of my script is: `#!/bin/zsh`

but it is never executed. It executes when run manually, but not when scheduled with the at utility.

Comment: Perhaps better on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Did you try using the -f flag? 
`at 13:00 -f /path/to/script.sh` ?

Comment: Is your script executable (`chmod +x <name_of_shell_script>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using [zsh](/questions/tagged/zsh), try using `sched` instead:

1. Add to your `.zshrc` file:

   ```
   zmodload zsh/sched
   ```
2. Restart your shell.
3. Use it as follows:

   ```
   sched 13:00 <absolute path to shell script>
   ```

See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002fsched-Module for more info.

Also, make sure your script file is actually set as executable:

```
chmod a+x <absolute path to shell script>
```